# calendy API error in php

Tags: php, api, http-status-code-404, calendly

I am trying to used calendy API in the php I used following code to make check the Authentication Token

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://calendly.com/api/v1/echo");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-TOKEN: <Token-code>",// My Token code here
  ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);?>
```

But I got error message 404 unauthorized

```
{
  "type": "authentication_error",
  "message": "Invalid token"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any one who used Calendy API can used like this way

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://calendly.com/api/v1/echo");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "X-TOKEN: TOKE-HERE",
  ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Can you post your `curl_post_data` values? I'm looking for the structure.

Comment: sorry, the client has changed calendy credentials.

Comment: has calendly changed its authentication, I am getting the following error

{"status":401,"type":"authentication_error","message":"Invalid token"}